# cross compilation on ccs

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, object-files

I am supposed to build a project using neon intrinsic and since CCS doesn't support neon intrinsic, I am compiling the program on cygwin command line using GCC and will later link it on CCS.

Now the problem is that I have got the object file . But I am not able to link it on CCS. I don't want to be spoon fed , just a basic set of steps that I need to follow will suffice.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a step-by-step:

https://linuxlink.timesys.com/docs/gsg/omapl138_exp

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/How_to_connect_to_the_OMAP-L138/C6748/AM1808_EVM_board_using_CCS%3F

Have fun.